# simple Extjs gridpanel implementation with php

Tags: php, extjs

Can any give working example of extjs Editorgridpanel with fetching data from php ,
i found some example but they didnt work for me

i tried , this, what wrong

my html

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<title>JSON Grid Example</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css" />        
 <script type="text/javascript" src="adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>     
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples/grid/grid-examples.css" />   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="extjson-grid.js"></script>    
   <h1>JSON Grid Example</h1>    
 <p>This example shows how to load a grid with JSON data.</p>      
 <div id="example-grid"></div>    
</head> 
</html>
```

my js

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 
      var proxy=new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:'connectextjs.php'}); 
      var reader=new Ext.data.JsonReader(
       [{name: 'Employee_ID', mapping: 'Employee_ID'},                 
        {name: 'Department_ID'},                            
        {name: 'Name'},                  
       {name: 'Email'}]                

var store = new  Ext.data.Store({proxy:proxy,reader:reader}); 
         store.load(); 
 create the grid     var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({ 
   store: store,         
   columns: [            
   {header: "Employee_ID", width: 90, dataIndex: 'Employee_ID', sortable: true},                 
   {header: "Department_ID", width: 90, dataIndex: 'Department_ID', sortable: true},             
   {header: "Name", width: 90, dataIndex: 'Name', sortable: true},             
{header: "Email", width: 200, dataIndex: 'Email', sortable: true}],
         renderTo:'example-grid',
         width:540,         height:200 
    }); 
});
```

my php code

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());    
// Retrieve all the data from the "employee" table
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees") or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
  // get data and store in a json array 
$query ="Select Employee_ID,Department_ID,Name,Email from Employees";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{     $myInventory[] = array(
     'Employee_ID' => $row['Employee_ID'], 
    'Department_ID' => $row['Department_ID'],     
'Name' => $row['Name'],     
'Email' => $row['Email'] ;   }

   $myData = $myInventory; 
echo json_encode($myData);
    ?>
```

Comment: Format your code nicely, nobody want to read messy code

Comment: why you put this code?
$query ="Select Employee_ID,Department_ID,Name,Email from Employees";

Comment: Your array is not closed.. Change to this: $myInventory[] = array(
    'Employee_ID' => $row['Employee_ID'],
    'Department_ID' => $row['Department_ID'],
    'Name' => $row['Name'],
    'Email' => $row['Email']
            );

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have this output from your php

A Sample JSON Data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Employee_ID": 1,
            "Department_ID": 1,
            "Name": "Abhishek Jaiswal",
            "Email": "ajaiswal@mail.com"
        },
        {
            "Employee_ID": 2,
            "Department_ID": 1,
            "Name": "John Doe",
            "Email": "jdoe@mail.com"
        },
        {
            "Employee_ID": 3,
            "Department_ID": 2,
            "Name": "Darick Pascua",
            "Email": "dpascua@mail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

To generate that Sample JSON Data use this code snippet:
records.php

```
$employeeRecords["data"] = array(
    array(
        "Employee_ID"   => 1,
        "Department_ID" => 1,
        "Name"          => "Abhishek Jaiswal",
        "Email"         => "ajaiswal@mail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "Employee_ID"   => 2,
        "Department_ID" => 1,
        "Name"          => "John Doe",
        "Email"         => "jdoe@mail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "Employee_ID"   => 3,
        "Department_ID" => 2,
        "Name"          => "Darick Pascua",
        "Email"         => "dpascua@mail.com"
    ),
);

echo json_encode($employeeRecords);
```

Your HTML, using cdn from sencha:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597001/simple-extjs-gridpanel-implementation-with-php</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/ext-theme-neptune/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

And finally your app.js, I've added comments for you:

```
/**
 * Your store here
 */
var EmployeeRecords = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad : true, //Autoload set it to true unless you want to load this manually
    fields:['Employee_ID', 'Department_ID', 'Name', 'Email'], //Set your model
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'records.php', //Actual data coming from the database
        reader: {
            type: 'json', //The type of the reader
            root: 'data'  //We set our root here
        }
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Simple Extjs Grid', //Application Name
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit', //We stretch our datagrid
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel', //Our grid panel
                    title: 'JSON Sample Data',
                    store: EmployeeRecords,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'Employee_ID',
                            header: 'Employee ID'
                        },
                        {
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'Department_ID',
                            header: 'Department ID'
                        },
                        {
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'Name',
                            header: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'Email',
                            header: 'Email'
                        },
                    ],
                    listeners: { //After render event listener
                        afterrender: function() {
                            alert("Datagrid FTW!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is The SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `Employee_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Department_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `employees` (`Employee_ID`, `Department_ID`, `Name`, `Email`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'Bagio', 'bagio@gmail.com'),
(2, 2, 'Sinchan', 'sinchan@gmail.com');
```

This is The PHP File (Employee.php):

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "extjs-test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Retrieve all the data from the "employee" table
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM employees";
if (($result = $mysqli->query($SQL)) === false) {
    printf("Invalid query: %s\nWhole query: %s\n", $mysqli->error, $SQL);
    exit();
}
$counter = 0;
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $myInventory["employees"][$counter] = array(
        'Employee_ID' => $obj->Employee_ID,
        'Department_ID' => $obj->Department_ID,
        'Name' => $obj->Name,
        'Email' => $obj->Email);
    $counter++;
}

$myData = $myInventory;
echo json_encode($myData);
?>
```

This is The HTML File:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>JSON Grid Example</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.onReady(function () {
                var mystore = new Ext.data.Store({proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: 'Employee.php'}),
                    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                        root: 'employees',
                        fields: [{name: 'Employee_ID'},
                            {name: 'Department_ID'},
                            {name: 'Name'},
                            {name: 'Email'}]
                    })
                });
                //create the grid     
                var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store: mystore,
                    title: 'MyGrid',
                    columns: [{
                            id: 'Employee_ID',
                            header: 'Employee ID',
                            width: 200,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'Employee_ID'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'Department_ID',
                            header: 'Department ID',
                            width: 200,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'Department_ID'
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Name',
                            width: 200,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Email',
                            width: 200,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'Email'
                        }],
                    renderTo: 'example-grid',
                    width: 540,
                    height: 200,
                    autoHeight: true
                });
                mystore.load();
            });
        </script>    
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <div id="example-grid"></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Try it. The error occurs because there are many unclosed array.
And the MySQL Select Query give deprecated error, so if You set apache warning ON, the Grid would not rendered cause it contains additional warning html from  deprecated mysql error.
Use MySQLI instead of deprecated mysql.